# Why does Doctrine say it can't find the PDO driver?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I tried Symfony 2 today and I tried to play a bit with Doctrine.

But when I use the command `php app/console doctrine:schema:create` in the command line, it returns this error:

```
[PDOException]
could not find driver

doctrine:schema:create [--dump-sql] [--em[="..."]]
```

My php.ini file and phpinfo() cleary show that the PDO driver is loaded. I also created a little script in pure PHP to connect to my database using PDO and it worked fine. No error, so PDO is well installed and works.

PHP and MySQL are running on my computer using the last version of EasyPHP.

What could have gone wrong with Doctrine? Where should I look now?

Comment: Have you run that little script from CLI too? What about `php -i`?

Comment: It doesn't work when a run the script from CLI... But why? Isn't the same php installation? :/ What Do I have to find in php -i?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to configure correctly your php cli, to load the same extensions that the web server version has configured to load.

Here is a [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) on where PHP searches for the configuration file

Comment: When I do `php -m` (list of compiled in modules) I can see PDO. There are two php.ini files in my directory (one of dev and on for prod) and I've found only these ones.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. The problem is due to a missing php.ini file for the CLI.

Comment: Type `php --ini` to see where the php.ini is located

Answer (score 20):

Yeah, if you type `php -m` at the command line, it should list both `PDO` and `pdo_mysql`.  In my case it showed only `PDO` which is why it could not find the MySQL driver.

As you've already commented, I think it's because the PHP CLI cannot find a suitable `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 10):

sudo apt-get install php5-mysql

will do the magic

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Ziumin Coming back and looking at this question this answer did indeed fix my problem. Not only is it a answer, but could possibly be the accepted answer on this question if expanded on.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Everything says PDO is installed and running, but Synfony can't find it.

Comment: This is the answer that solved it for me (although accounting for PHP versions, I had to use `sudo apt install php7.3-mysql`).

Answer (score 4):

On command line, check if you have PDO support:

```
php -m|grep -i pdo
```

If not, search for php mysql support (Ubuntu):

```
apt-cache search php5*|grep mysql
```

And install it:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

After installing the packagem check again, you should see the PDO mysql support.

Comment: fwiw in 2024 this appeared to work for me: `sudo apt-get install php-mysql`

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the error is not specific toward which driver it's missing.  In my case, I had PDO and PDO_MYSQL, but it also required PDO_sqlsrv.

Run `php app/console doctrine:schema:create -vvv` for better specifics.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've tried to run bin/console from a local terminal and not from the docker container.

Maybe it will help the others!

Answer (score 0):

If you're editing php.ini in your php install, that .ini file is the one specified in phpinfo(), AND your php.ini changes still aren't showing up with a symfony project you need to create a php.ini in your project's root directory and add the values you want to override there.

**Scan this dir for additional .ini files** should now show your projects root directory.

**Additional .ini files parsed** should show the new project specific php.ini file.

(I'm getting a Symfony 3.3 app to run locally)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I installed the doctrine with the command bellow, in laravel 7.x project.

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

So the composer installed the last doctrine/dbal version in my laravel 7.x project, then this error appered.

So, could be the doctrine/dbal version too.