# Doctrine can't find the PostgreSQL PDO driver?

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I see this question is very similar but I have PDO and pdo_pgsql installed

- [Why does Doctrine say it can't find the PDO driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451945/why-doctrine-says-it-can-not-find-the-pdo-driver)

Here is my error message:

```
 php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml ./src/Vendor/Bundle/MyBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force



  [PDOException]         
  could not find driver  



doctrine:mapping:convert [--filter="..."] [--force] [--from-database] [--extend[="..."]] [--num-spaces[="..."]] [--namespace[="..."]] [--em[="..."]] to-type dest-path
```

Here is my config.yml settings

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
      connections:
        my_database:
          driver:   pdo_pgsql
          port:     5432
          dbname:   blah
          user:     foo
          password: bar
          charset:  UTF8
```

The host is configured in the prod and dev yaml files like this

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
      connections:
        my_database:
          host: localhost
```

running `php -m` on the command line I see that PDO, pdo_pgsql and pgsql are all installed

```
PDO
pdo_pgsql
pgsql
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Ugh..

You have to setup the default database first in the parameters.yml file

Well that's what worked for me

Answer (score 2):

In Symfony 2.7 or more the problem is resolved by editing the *app/config/config.yml* file to leave it to the database which indicates the driver:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: "%database_driver%"
```

This solution is also useful when multiple databases of different drivers are used, for example, a MySQL database , another PostgreSQL database, ...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, verify your **php.ini** file: the extensions *php_pdo_pgsql* and *php_pdo* must be enabled. Make sure you apply this changes on php.ini file that your **symfony project** is using (I imagine you are using the tool app/console from symfony), check this on *localhost/path_to_your_project/web/config.php*. You know if this extensions are enabled executing the function phpinfo().

This command is also helpfull: php -m. It lists on console all the php modules that are loaded.

Tip: check out you **Apache error log**, there could be something wrong with the load of your extensions. This file is located according to your server configuration.

Comment: And set the extention_dir correctly in php.ini