# Schema-Tool failed with Error 'could not find driver'

Tags: php, symfony, pdo

I'm facing a problem in symfony doctrine create table

```
TTENTION: This operation should not be executed in a production environment.

Creating database schema...



  [Doctrine\ORM\Tools\ToolsException]
  Schema-Tool failed with Error 'could not find driver' while executing DDL: CREATE TABLE Card (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, encrypted_id VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, Type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, Nb_s
  can INT NOT NULL, Id_user INT DEFAULT NULL, INDEX IDX_B62637EDC90EF3D7 (Id_user), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB






  [PDOException]
  could not find driver



doctrine:schema:create [--dump-sql] [--em[="..."]]
```

I have install pdo module.

```
php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
Core
ctype
date
dom
ereg
fileinfo
filter
hash
intl
json
libxml
mhash
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

parameters.yml

```
parameters:

    database_driver:   pdo_mysql
    database_host:     127.0.0.1
    database_port:     ~
    database_name:     sofid
    database_user:     sofid
    database_password: sofid

    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: ~
    mailer_password: ~
    locale: en
```

Comment: Have you tried to google for the error message?

Comment: have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451945/why-doctrine-says-it-can-not-find-the-pdo-driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install php5-mysql

In ubuntu: sudo apt-get install php5-mysql