# Symfony SQLite3 and PDO drivers

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, pdo, sqlite

I'm running Symfony but it doesn't find pdo drivers and the demo application throws exception of SQLite3 exceptions.
The configuration checkers says:

> PDO should have some drivers installed (currently available: none)
>   Install PDO drivers (mandatory for Doctrine).

But in php.ini I have:

> extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
>   extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
>   extension=php_sqlite3.dll

In the end, the symfony app says:

```
// Check if SQLite is enabled
        if ($isDriverException && $this->isSQLitePlatform() && !extension_loaded('sqlite3')) {
            $event->setException(new \Exception('PHP extension "sqlite3" must be enabled because, by default, the Symfony Demo application uses SQLite to store its information.'));
        }
```

But I knew that with PHP 5.3+ it's installed by default.
I'm running on windows with PHP7.1 installed

Comment: Have a look at this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451945/why-does-doctrine-say-it-cant-find-the-pdo-driver

Comment: Thank you. I'm really dumb. My problem was that I hadn't restarted my server... lol